# error code "INVALID_USERID" when attempting to retrieve document from REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm fetching signed and completed documents for my application so that I can host them on my own site. When attempting to access any endpoint for my account at /v2.1/accounts//..., I receive an INVALID_USERID error.

I am having this issue on the live environment, I have successfully made these requests on the demo environment. I have tried both the numerical ID and the guid.

I am using the JWT Grant method for authentication. I have ensured that I have granted consent for the account that my API is impersonating.

request

```
GET https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<account_id>
Authorization: bearer <redacted>
Content-Type: application/json
Host: www.docusign.net
```

response

```
{
          "Cache-Control" => "no-cache",
         "Content-Length" => "58",
           "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   "Vary" => "Accept-Encoding"
}

{
  "errorCode" => "INVALID_USERID",
    "message" => "Invalid UserId."
}
```

I cannot seem to find anything in the docs mentioning this case specifically.

Answer (score 0):

when using JWT the call is made on behalf of some user in the system. So the authentication for the token is not for a specific user but the userId has to be specified. 
see here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken the request includes what we call "sub" which is the user Id for the user.
You have to check to make sure the GUID for that user is the correct/valid ID for an active user in that account.